# Diplay items for category PHP and echo categories as link to each view

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello im learning so im sorry if this is a fool question. (also sorry about my bad english)

Im trying to display the items from a particular category.

In my Database, i have set my categories like this.

[image: Categories]

And the Products or Items like this,

[image: items]

Im using this code to display tree categories.

```
function hasChild($parent_id)
  {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM category WHERE parent_id = '" . $parent_id . "'";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    return $rs['count'];
  }

  function CategoryTree($list,$parent,$append)
  {
    $list = '<li>'.$parent['name'].'</li>';

    if (hasChild($parent['id'])) // check if the id has a child
    {
      $append++;
      $list .= "<ul class='child child".$append."'>";
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = '" . $parent['id'] . "'";
      $qry = mysql_query($sql);
      $child = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
      do{
        $list .= CategoryTree($list,$child,$append);
      }while($child = mysql_fetch_array($qry));
      $list .= "</ul>";
    }
    return $list;
  }
  function CategoryList()
  {
    $list = "";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE (parent_id = 0 OR parent_id IS NULL)";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
    $parent = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    $mainlist = "<ul class='parent'>";
    do{
      $mainlist .= CategoryTree($list,$parent,$append = 0);
    }while($parent = mysql_fetch_array($qry));
    $list .= "</ul>";
    return $mainlist;
  }
```

But i cant find a good way to convert the categories in links, so each time a users clic one category i will display the items for that category..

What would be the best for that.

If you can point me in the right direction, some tutorial, or something, would be really , really great.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for some sort of java tree viewer, like this example?
http://dftree.sourceforge.net/dftree/example.html

There are several open source options for this (I have no experience of the one I list above, I just use it as an example). I'm sure I have used a tree viewer in the past that took a list format like you are using - I suggest you have a search around sourceforge.

Your question is not foolish, but is quite long... and many of us are quite lazy :-)

Comment: Ok I will edit my question as i have found everything just need a way to send some variables in the URL.. do you know a good link for that.. :D thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solve this

This is the code for the page with the menu and categories

```
<?php



  function hasChild($parent_id)
  {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM category WHERE parent_id = '" . $parent_id . "'";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    return $rs['count'];
  }

  function CategoryTree($list,$parent,$append)
  {
      $productpage = "index.php"; 

    $list = '<li><a href='.$productpage.'?'.'cat='.$parent['id'].'>'.$parent['name'].'</a></li>';

    if (hasChild($parent['id'])) // check if the id has a child
    {
      $append++;
      $list .= "<ul class='child child".$append."'>";
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = '" . $parent['id'] . "'";
      $qry = mysql_query($sql);
      $child = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
      do{
        $list .= CategoryTree($list,$child,$append);
      }while($child = mysql_fetch_array($qry));
      $list .= "</ul>";
    }
    return $list;
  }
  function CategoryList()
  {
    $list = "";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE (parent_id = 0 OR parent_id IS NULL)";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
    $parent = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    $mainlist = "<ul class='parent'>";
    do{
      $mainlist .= CategoryTree($list,$parent,$append = 0);
    }while($parent = mysql_fetch_array($qry));
    $list .= "</ul>";
    return $mainlist;
  }
?>
```

And the code for the product page

```
<?php 

$producto = mysql_escape_string($_GET['producto']);

$tablename = "productos";


$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$tablename` WHERE `id` = '$producto'");

                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

                     $uid = $row["id"]; 
    $titulo = $row["titulo"];  
    $descripcion = $row["descripcion"];  
    $modelo = $row["modelo"];  
    $img = $row["img"];  
    // echo the output to browser or compound an output variables here 
    echo "ID = $uid 
    <br />Titulo = $titulo
    <br>Descripcion = $descripcion 
    <br>Modelo = $modelo
    <br>Imagen = <img src=\"../admin/$img\" width=\"40px\" height=\"40px\" >
    <hr />"; 


?>
```